# Algebird HyperLogLog - Register Index and Register Value Bits

Tags: postgresql, scala, twitter, monoids, abstract-algebra

I am new to HyperLogLog and Scala, and am trying to use the Twitter Algebird's HyperLogLog implementation - https://github.com/twitter/algebird/blob/develop/algebird-core/src/main/scala/com/twitter/algebird/HyperLogLog.scala.

In other implementations of HyperLogLog (like this one for Postgres https://github.com/aggregateknowledge/postgresql-hll) I am able to tune the algorithm with the number of buckets (using log2m) as well as the width of the registers based on my expected carnality and accuracy requirements.

I am having trouble understanding how these values are used/computed in the Algebird implementation.  Specifically I am using the `HyperLogLogMonoid` class.

Answer (score 0):

The only parameter of the HyperLogLog algorithm is the number of buckets `m`, where `m = 2 ^ b`. The `HyperLogLogMonoid` is parametrized by `val bits: Int`, which is the the equivalent of the parameter `b` in the original paper.

Comment: I do understand this part.  But in other parts of the code I am seeing calculations for `reducedBits The new number of bits to use` and `jLen` which appear to be adjusting the actual number of bits being used for `m`.  But as I mentioned, I am new to the algorithm and Scala, and am having trouble understanding the code clearly.

Comment: `reducedBits` is used in the method `downsize`. This method is used to return a new HLL instance with reduced number of bits used to represent your HyperLogLog structure, this way decreasing the memory used for your computation and increasing the standard error.

Comment: Yes, I can see that.  I actually trying to understand when how these reduced bits are actually calculated and used.

Comment: as far as I see, it's not used from anywhere, it's just a utility function to safely resize the HLL structure